# How to define a function pointer for a function returning a 2-dimensional array?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, function-pointers, virtual-functions

I have written this program that defines a function to return a 1-dimensional array and a typedef declaration of a function pointer for the same. An instance of the function pointer is used to invoke the function `my_num`.

```
typedef int* (*get_max_ports_t)(void);
int arr[4] = {3,4,5,6};

int (*my_num(void)) {
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    get_max_ports_t get_max_ports;
    get_max_ports = &my_num;

    int *x = get_max_ports();
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

I now want to write a similar program to return a 2-dimensional array and a typedef declaration of a function pointer to invoke the function through an instance. I have been able to write the function, but am unable to understand how to define the typedef declaration and instance assignment as my understanding of pointers is a bit sketchy here.

```
// typdef pointer declaration here
int arr[2][2] = {{3,4},{5,6}};

int (*my_num(void))[2] {
    return arr;
}


int main()
{
    // create typedef instance and attach to my_num()

    int (*x)[2] = my_num(); // call function through typedef instance
    printf("%d\t%d\n", x[0][0], x[0][1]);
    printf("%d\t%d\n", x[1][0], x[1][1]);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried specifying the column size of the 2-dimensional array as a part of the typedef declaration (`typedef int ((*get_max_ports_t)(void)[2])`), and also declaring as a double pointer (`typedef int* ((**get_max_ports_t)(void))`), but both resulted in compilation errors.

Answer (score 1):

Use a typedef for the function return type.

```
typedef int (*my_arr_ptr_type)[2];
my_arr_ptr_type my_arr = arr;

my_arr_ptr_type my_func(void)
{
    return my_arr;
}

typedef my_arr_ptr_type (*my_func_ptr_type)(void);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/h8s7ET185)

Answer (score 1):

You have a clue in your own `int (*x)[2] = ...` declaration.

Just make the array pointer `typedef`, here called `ap`, into:

```c
typedef int(*ap)[2];
```

Full example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

// typedef pointer declaration here
typedef int(*ap)[2];

int arr[2][2] = {{3,4},{5,6}};

ap my_num(void) {
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    // create typedef instance and attach to my_num()
    ap x = my_num();  // call function through typedef instance

    printf("%d\t%d\n", x[0][0], x[0][1]);
    printf("%d\t%d\n", x[1][0], x[1][1]);
    return 0;
}
```